# Using one of the parameters in 'write' function for Linux Character Device Driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am a student who is trying to learn about Linux character Device Driver. I've been following the tutorial which is written [here](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/06/generic-hardware-access-in-linux/#) with some modifications. The read and write system calls for this driver only read and write on a char buffer. The problem is that it seems to me the parameter loff_t *off changes its value when it is supposed no to do that. What I mean is, if you see the next piece of code.

```c
static ssize_t my_write(struct file *f, const char __user *buf,
    size_t len, loff_t *off){
int i;
char byte;
printk(KERN_INFO "Driver: write()\n");
printk(KERN_INFO "1. The value of *off is:%i\n",*off);
if (*off >= (BUFFER_SIZE - 1)){
        return 0;
    }
printk(KERN_INFO "2. The value of *off is:%i\n",*off);
    if ((*off + len) > (BUFFER_SIZE - 1)){
        len = BUFFER_SIZE - 1 - *off;
    }
printk(KERN_INFO "3. The value of *off is:%i\n",*off);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (copy_from_user(&byte, buf + i, 1)){
                return -EFAULT;
        }
        c[i]=byte;
    }
printk(KERN_INFO "4. The value of *off is:%i\n",*off);
c[len]='\n';
*off += len;
printk(KERN_INFO "5. The value of *off is:%i\n",*off);
    return len;
}
```

The outcomes on the console for the printk calls are:

1. The value of *off is:0
2. The value of *off is:-1
3. The value of *off is:0
4. The value of *off is:693260
5. The value of *off is:-2132049164

Could you tell me why? Thank you.

Comment: The link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713112/understanding-loff-t-offp-for-file-operations could help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the Chapter 3: Char Drivers in LDD...

`off` is a pointer to a “long offset type” object that indicates the file position the user is accessing.

Whatever the amount of data the methods transfer, they should generally update the
file position at *offp to represent the current file position after successful completion
of the system call.

For more information refer Figure 3-2 in https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch03.pdf