# why does the write() system call have 3 parameters whereas the driver code for write() has 4?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, system-calls

I am new to linux device drivers. I see that the fops structures defines write as ::

```
static ssize_t device_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
```

whereas the write function in the userspace program uses 3 parameters?

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);
```

What happens to the offset parameter `loff_t`?

Comment: The `device_write` which you are seeing is the last function in the chain of "write" callbacks from user space to kernel; which actually talks to hardware (or some pseudo implementation) Linux kernel has an abstraction for file system related calls which is called VFS. The `offset` is handled there, so that user do not have to worry when writing. However you can still access the offset by making appropriate "seek" call. Hope this helps.

Comment: Some more information about offset can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713112/understanding-loff-t-offp-for-file-operations

Comment: Thanks , that is the answer i was looking for.